# H.264 auxiliary picture = alpha channel?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, alpha

H.264 standard (ITU-T Rec. H.264 (02/2014) Advanced video coding) describe "Auxiliary Pictures" which  are optional for decoding and can be used for such purposes as alpha blending.

Also, at document "7.4.2.1.2 Sequence parameter set extension RBSP semantics" has a **alpha_transparent_value** can be set.
[And I found QuickTime Movie support alpha setting.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21189?locale=en_US)

But what I know is H.264 is not support alpha channel. What is this "Auxiliary Picture"? For alpha channel? If it's yes, how H.264 compress it? Do it have some samples?

Answer (score 0):

The H.264 standard describes alpha channel encoding through auxiliary picture. But I have never seen a decoder or encoder supporting it.
So to my knowledge - yes there is standard for H.264 with alpha but to me there is no known implementation.
So you would have to implement or modify existing H.264 decoder/encoder which is a substantial task.

I think the situation is even worse - I don't know of any popular cross platform video format with alpha. On Apple I'd use Apple ProRes 4444 - but you may have a hard time creating ProRes files on anything but macOS.

Currently HAP is gaining traction - https://hap.video/ which has alpha support.